# Apple-app-site-association not validation "Error cannot parse app site association"

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, apple-app-site-associate

I am using apple's tool for app site association validation found here: https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool

It gives me the error "Error cannot parse app site association"
However I have successfully downloaded the file both at /apple-app-site-association and at /.well-known/apple-app-site-association and both downloads and seems to be correct json.

The domain I am trying to validate are app.skyresponse.com

My webserver log confirms successful get and other third-party tools confirm apple-app-site-association configuration seems to be correct.
( https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ )

I am serving the file from AWS S3 thru AWS Cloudfront and have been experimenting back and forth with every setting there is, from content-type to SSL certificate version support.

Anyone that can shed some light on this? it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigation I found the reason myself.

I had a index.html file in the root of the webserver that had a header section containing

https://skyresponse.com/" />

When this was present, apple validation tool was not even trying to download the apple-app-site-association file. But presented the error as "Error cannot parse app site association")

Comment: Hi, I am running into very similar issues (the AASA files passes validation with  https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/ but gives me `Error cannot parse app site association` with https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool). I am curious what you meant regarding the index.html file. You just modified the index.html file and then magically deep linking started working ?

Comment: @DidierProphete I know your comment is from 2 years ago but have you found a solution, if you remember?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu: I did. I can't remember what my exact error was to be fair. But now my site association file works properly... Are you running into the same 'cannot parse' error ?

Comment: @DidierProphete yup, whatever I tried we couldnt get it to work. For business requiremenets, we've ended up using `.page.link` approach of Firebase (which isn't a good way but was the best in our case given constraints). I still have no idea why it wasn't working though.